# How to set up dc.js x axis for dates

Tags: charts, dc.js

I have a CSV file with 2 columns, in the first I have got some dates, in the second there are some values.

How do I initialize the x axis to show dates?

Comment: Which problems? Could you provide more details?

Comment: I have a CSV file with the dates in the first colum and the values in the second column. I can't put the dates of the CSV file in my timeseries chart, generated with DC.js library...how can I do put the date in domain of x axis? @il_raffa

Comment: Edited your question for clarity, please check. I can dig up an example Monday. It's true, we're missing a specific example of setting up a date axis, but looking at the `moveChart` and `volumeChart` of the [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO solving your problem consists of two parts:

1. Parsing the date in your data to a dc manageable format
2. coding the chart

For parsing the date, you need to use a function like this after injecting your csv file in the script:

```
    var parseDate = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-07:00").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.TxnDate = parseDate(d.TxnDate);
    });
```

Please note that the parse criteria might be different based on your data, in that case please check this [time formatting article](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)

For the second part, here is a sample chart definition but before that you need to define two new variables which will serve as the start and end point of our X axis. Define them like this after you have defined your dimensions and groups:

```
    var minDate = transactionDate.bottom(1)[0].TxnDate;
var maxDate = transactionDate.top(1)[0].TxnDate;
```

The code for your chart will be like this:

```
timeChart
.width(650)
.height(250)
.transitionDuration(1000)
.brushOn(false)
.dimension(transactionDate) //your dimension created from crossfilter
.group(fakeTxnDateGroup) // your group
.elasticY(true)
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.renderVerticalGridLines(true)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate])) //these are the dates we created before this step so that the scale fits according to our data
.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
```

I hope this helps you. In case it doesn't, do leave a js fiddle.
Thanks!

Comment: Probably needs `.xUnits()` to get the bar widths right? Also, this skips the aggregation by day/hour/minute, which is another tricky part.

Comment: @Gordon I'm having the exact problem that I think your comment would fix: pencil-thin bars for each date in an x-axis time spread. How do I set the width using .xUnits() so that the bar-chart looks normal? Data is dates (zero'ed time element)

Comment: Hi @CodeMantle, typically you will set xUnits with the [time interval](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#time-intervals-d3-time) range corresponding to the time bins you are aggregating, like `d3.timeDays` or `d3.timeMonths`. (Note the plural form is the range and the singular form is the binning function.) This tells the chart how many bars will appears and it calculates the width from that.

Comment: @Gordon In relation to setting xUnits, can you review this question I posted, with hopefully all the necessary code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783313/how-to-make-columns-wide-not-pencil-thin-on-dc-barchart-with-time-x-axis ?